# knitr .Rmd vignettes do not appear with vignette()

Tags: r, package, knitr

In a package I'm developing with R Studio, I create vignettes via `devtools::use_vignette("mydoc.Rnw")`, which gives a standard vignette header like

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Michael Friendly"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

I have followed all the instructions in http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html.  The vignettes **are** listed on the CRAN page for the package, yet they seem inaccessible in an R session with the package loaded.

```
 > browseVignettes("matlib")
 No vignettes found by browseVignettes("matlib") 

> library(tools)
> names(vignetteEngine(package = 'matlib'))
Error in getEngine(name, package) : 
  None of packages ‘matlib’ have registered vignette engines
```

I know that other packages with `knitr`-processed .Rmd vignettes are accessible from the package, but can't figure out why mine are not.
What is missing?

My `vignettes/` directory contains only the .Rmd files (no PDFs), but that seems the same as, e.g., https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/vignettes.

Comment: did you check the `use roxygen to generate vignettes` box in configure build tools and are you building the vignettes when you install the package?

Comment: I now have the `use roxygen to generate vignettes` box checked, and `Build & reload` now generates HTML files in the `vignettes/` directory. However, I still get `No vignettes found by browseVignettes("matlib")`.

Comment: Further question on this process:  should `vignettes/*.html` be added to `.gitignore` or `.Rbuildignore` ?

Comment: Ah! I had to run `devtools::build_vignettes()`.  This moved the `vignettes/*.html` files to `inst/doc` and added `inst/doc` to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Vignette is part of the package and should not be ignored. Built vignette can be ignored, as it will be rebuilt on each build.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Note **devtools** does not build vignettes by default when you `devtools::install()` (same thing for some `install_*` functions like `install_github()`) a package from a directory. You have to specify the argument `build_vignettes = TRUE` when you install the package. Currently there is no way to build vignettes using **devtools** if you just use the RStudio button `Build & Reload`. You have to `Build Source Package`, and run `R CMD INSTALL` on the tarball. Or run `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)` in the R console.

Comment: That clarifies things considerably.  Might be useful to add something on this to http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/

Comment: @user101089 Good suggestion. I'll do it.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I find a dark magic which can work around this situation.

From `Configure Build Tools...`, RStudio allows us to custom options for `R CMD INSTALL` when you click the `Build & Reload` button. In current implementation, it behaves like running `R CMD INSTALL [options] pkg` at the *parent* directory of the package directory.
It turns out that these options can be arbitrary strings, even including `;`, thus enable us to run bash commands.

For example, we can specify `-v; cd pkg; cp vignettes/*html inst/doc; R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source .; echo`

In this way, `-v` nullify RStudio's `R CMD INSTALL`. Then we can copy built html files in `vignette/` to `inst/doc/` before we install the package using our own `R CMD INSTALL`. (`cd pkg;` frees us from type package name multiple times in subsequent commands. `echo` nullify the package name appended by RStudio.

I know there are many drawbacks in this trick, such as hard-coding package name which is error prone if the package name is changed latter.

> Use it at your own risk.

Hope RStudio will comes out a elegant solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

On my end, using `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)` would solve the vignettes problem: `browseVignettes("mypackage")` would work normally. But every time I tried to open a help file `?myfunction`, there would be an error message:

```
Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database 
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/mypackage/help/mypackage.rdb' is corrupt
```

The safest way to solve both issues, in my opinion, is to do `R CMD build mypackage` and `R CMD INSTALL mypackage.1.0.tar.gz`.