# Access to a vignette of a particular package

Tags: r, package, knitr, vignette

I have just created a "toy" R package. The package includes the `vignettes` folder with two documents:

- `vignette.Rmd`: with the code used to generate the vignette
- `vignette.html`: which is the result after pressing the `knitr` button in R studio.

After installing correctly the package (I have got access to all the functions) when I run `browseVignettes("name_of_package")` I get the following message:

```
                 `No vignettes found by browseVignettes("name_of_package")`
```

I read some posts like [knitr .Rmd vignettes do not appear with vignette()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614660/knitr-rmd-vignettes-do-not-appear-with-vignette) but I didn't solve the problem. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of `list.files(system.file("doc", package = "name_of_package"))`?

Comment: The result is `character(0)`

Comment: This tells us that the vignette was not installed. How did you install the package? Which commands with which options?

Comment: I used the `install_github()` function because the code is on GitHub

Comment: With which options? In particular, did you use `build_vignettes = TRUE` as explained in the post you referenced?

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I uninstalled the package and installed again with the `build_vignettes = TRUE` option and it finally worked.