# Package build fails because vignette does not find child Rmd files

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-package

I have modularized my vignette Rmd file using `child` chunks to be able to reuse the child Rmd files in other Rmd documents.

The package build fails (in RStudio and with `R CMD build .`) with this error message:

```
** installing vignettes
   ‘Vignette.Rmd’ using ‘UTF-8’ 
Warning in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
  cannot open file 'child_doc.Rmd': No such file or directory
Quitting from lines 10-11 (child_doc.Rmd) 
Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
```

**How can I build my package (make R find my child Rmd files)?**

Example Rmd files:

Vignette.Rmd

````
---
title: "title"
author: "me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{title}
  %\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}

main doc

```{r child = "child_doc.Rmd"}
```
````

child_doc.Rmd:

```
# This is from the child doc
lorem ipsum
```

**Update 1:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49463061/4468078 indicates that RStudio builds the vignettes with the package folder as root (which could explain why the files are not found).

**Update 2:**

If have created a minimal reproducible example package together with a summary of the findings at github:

https://github.com/aryoda/R_pkg_knitr_child_vignette_issue

**Update 3:**

I have opened an issue at `knitr` (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1540) but @user2554330 has identified the `tools` namespace as one reason of problems...

**Update 4:**

See the bugzilla bug entry opened by Duncan Murdoch: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug (or maybe more than one).  I'd probably call it a bug in R, but it might be a bug in `knitr`.  When you build the tarball, R copies the main file into `inst/doc`, but not the child file.  `knitr` then looks at it and since it doesn't see the child, it quits.

To get the package to build, you just need an empty file in `inst/doc` with the same name as the child file.  But this isn't enough to pass checks.

When checking the package, R will see that child file sitting in `inst/doc`, and get upset because it's not a proper vignette.  So you need to fool R into thinking it is one.

As far as I can see, there's an easy (though ugly) workaround.  Just put a file named `child_doc.Rmd` into the `inst/doc` directory.  To make R think it is a vignette, copy the lines

```
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{title}
  %\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
```

from the main file.  Otherwise, the content appears to be irrelevant, so I wouldn't put anything else there.

Put the real `child_doc.Rmd` file into the `vignettes` directory.  I think if you do this, your package will build and check without errors.

This is probably worth a bug report, but I'm not sure what the fix should be.  Maybe `knitr` should be more tolerant in its check, or maybe R should copy the file sooner.

Too bad the workaround is so ugly, and will probably cause other problems once the bug is fixed.

Comment: Great analysis! I would classify this as bug too. What happens if you (without applying your described workarounds) call `devtools::build_vignettes()`? After that I do not get any error or warning anymore during build or check, but `inst/doc` does still **not** contain the child Rmd file.

Comment: That passes the build but fails the check for me.

Comment: I am using R3.4.4 too (on Linux), I will try to build using Windows and another R version tomorrow. Thanks for your help, I am debugging into the code now and try to identify R or knitr as the source of the problems to be able to open an issue. Currently it looks like `tools::buildVignettes` is not the problem if called with the right args (R CMD build + check call this function according the help). I will accept your answer since you have provided a work-around. THX!

Comment: The problem seems to be in `tools::.install_package_vignettes2`, which calls `tools::pkgVignettes` on the `doc` directory without copying all the files.  I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Wow, deep diving in the code :-) Good to hear that. I have already opened an issue at github for knitr, perhaps you could link your ticket to enable a big picture: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1540

Comment: Duncan Murdoch has already filed a bug report for R, see: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17416